# Open TK Ray Casting / Intersection with part

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, opentk, raycasting

I currently am writing a CAD type viewer with Open TK.  I have most of it complete in terms of it loading a file, displaying it, proper lighting, rotating, etc.  What I am now trying to figure out is how to figure out where on my object I have clicked. I have found that ray casting is probably what I am looking to do but how do I determine where **on my part** the ray intersects?

My part is drawn with a normal vector and three points, per triangle.  I have my environment set to smooth so much of the shape is approximated by Open TK upon drawing.

Correct me if I am wrong but I would think that the view window can be thought of as a rectangular cylinder slicing through the object, and the point on the view window can simply follow that same angle into the part:

[image]

If this is correct, then it should be relatively easy to establish the ray but my question still exists of how to tell where this ray intersects my part? I am trying to get an actual (x,y,z) coordinate of where this intersection happens.  I will eventually use this as a method to set the camera's focus to the point clicked on so that things such as rotation happen with that new point as the focus.

Any help would be appreciated and any solution can be in either VB .NET or C#.

Thanks!

Comment: The "viewbox" only works if you use orthogonal projection, with perspective projection you have to work with a pyramid, and the construction of the ray is less straightforward. Assuming you have an orthogonal projection, all you need next is finding the collision point between a line and a surface. If this surface consists of triangles, you need a ray-triangle intersection. Smarter people than me have thought long and hard about how to do this fast, so you better google it. If the surface does not consist of triangles, then you will have to make a custom approach for the type of surface.

Comment: So there is no open gl / open tk function to detect collision with an object? Also, if my view is more like a pyramid, how would I establish my ray then? Would it be a different angle than the one my camera has with the focal point?

Comment: Opengl does not have such a thing, although i think GLUT has some helper functions to make it easier. The technique is called "picking" and I think openTK has support for it, so google that. And yes, the angle would be different than the focal point if your mouse is not at the exact center of the screen.

Comment: How would I go determining the new angle?

Comment: Well, you're better off just googling picking and taking one of the pre-made openTK functions, but it works something like this. Get the inverse of your view-projection matrix and use it to generate 2 points: One for the mouse position on your nearplane, and one for the mouse position on your far plane. Then the line between these two points is the line you should test your collisions against.